# LinkedIn Company Feed SharePoint web part

Tags: api, sharepoint, linkedin-api

I've been playing around with the LinkedIn API and OAuth2 which I have managed to get working in a C# web application and it grabs the updates from the DevTestCo in this particular instance.

What I would like to do is convert this to a SharePoint web part! I've got some experience of developing SharePoint web parts. The bit I'm getting hung up on is when you get the access code for oauth2 and then request the token you have to redirect for both requests. Which I think will confuse the user if this happens every time.

The only way I can think of getting around this is to store the access token and refresh this every n number of days. This means only one user will be redirected every 45 days but it seems like a little bit of a hack.

Has anyone tried doing this or thought of a better way since the updates to the LinkedIn API in 2015?

Cheers

Truez